# How do compare a single value from one table to another list of values in another table

Tags: mysql, select, compare, comparison-operators

I have two tables and I would like to compare one value to see if it is less than another value.
Considering the two example tables I want to make a SELECT statement that would tell me, given my wallet amount which items I could afford.   How do I say:

```
SELECT product FROM Store WHERE price < amount
```

The above obviously does not work I have searched everywhere.

Wallet:

```
name       amount
--------------
Mymoney     20
```

Store:

```
product |  price
-----------------------
Apple   |  3
Orange  |  4
Steak   |  21
```

Comment: Select * from product inner join wallet on price <= mymoney

Comment: I have bananas to sell you at 19.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with 2 diferent tables, you should use some kind of join like:

```
select product from Store inner join Wallet on price <= Mymoney
```

sqlFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b431a2/4

Comment: I see what you mean, I thought i could solve my problem by asking a simpler question but what I am dealing with is a table with Customers which have a certain spending limit and the other table consists of essentially items for purchase,

Comment: and I needed a single individual customers spending limit as opposed to all of the spending limits/wallets.

Comment: you can always add an "and" clause at the end that specifies the customer that you want to check, like "select product from Store inner join Wallet on price <= Mymoney and custumerId = '1'"